# Android update app across app restarts using DownloadManager (avoid downloading multiple times)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager, sticky-broadcast

Iam trying to update my app by downloading the apk using download manager. I have registered broadcast receiver to listen to `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` in `MainActivity` and open the apk in `onReceive` method.
Following is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {
private long downloadReference;
private DownloadManager downloadManager;
private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, intentFilter);

}

public void updateApp(String url) {
    //start downloading the file using the download manager
    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myapk.apk");
    downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //unregister your receivers
    this.unregisterReceiver(downloadReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (downloadReference == referenceId) {

            //start the installation of the latest version
                    Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                installIntent.setDataAndType(downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadReference),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(installIntent);

        }

    }

};

}
```

`updateApp(url)` is called on click of a button in UI.
Now after clicking the button, the download starts. Lets say the app is closed (receiver is unregistered) after initiating the download, I have problem with two scenarios when the app is started again.

1. The previous download completes after my app is restarted -
   `downloadReference` is lost and when my receiver receives the broadcast, the `referenceId` wont be same as `downloadReference`, so `installIntent` is never started. So
   I have to click on Update button again and initiate the download. Is
   there a way to avoid this problem?
2. The previous download completes before my app is restarted - There is no way of knowing that my previous download is complete in
   the newly started activity. Again I have to click the button and reinitiate the download. Is there a way to enable sticky
   broadcast for download manager?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to store the download reference in your preference. Then you can query the DownloadManager using [DownloadManager.Query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Query.html) which will return a cursor holding all the download requests posted to `DownloadManager` by your app. Then you can match the `downloadReference` id and then check the status of your download. If it's complete then you can get the path from `DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME`.

```
private void updateDownloadStatus(long downloadReference) {      
  DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();

  // if you have stored the downloadReference. Else you have to loop through the cursor.
  query.setFilterById(downloadReference); 

  Cursor cursor = null;

  try {
    cursor = DOWNLOAD_MANAGER.query(query);
    if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      // restart download
      return;
    }
    float bytesDownloaded =
        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
    float bytesTotal =
        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
    int downloadStatus = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
    int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
    int failureStatus = cursor.getInt(columnReason);
    int filePathInt = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(filePathInt);

    switch (downloadStatus) {
      case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
      case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ERROR:
        // restart download
        break;

      case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
        if (filePath != null) {
          //got the file 
        } else {
          //restart
        }
        break;

      case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
      case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
      case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
        /// wait till download finishes
        break;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error","message" + e.getMessage(), e);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```